# executable do not run after static linking with library

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, static-linking

In my Makefile, I have tried build a code static linking with a library from another project I have in my computer. I have this instruction:

```
game: Input.o Image.o Renderer.o Surface.o Main.o
    g++ -g -L ${sdl_library} -L ${lib_netpbm_library} -o release/game2d build/Input.o build/Image.o build/Renderer.o build/Surface.o build/Main.o -l:libnetpbm.a -l:libSDL2.a -l:libSDL2main.a -lGL -lGLEW -lm
```

It builds with no error or warning. But when I try run the generated executable, I got this error:

```
./game2d: error while loading shared libraries: libnetpbm.a: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Clearly regardless of your intentions the linker is linking this as a shared library not a static library.  I don't understand this syntax `-l:libnetpbm.a`: what is the `:` here for?  I've not seen that before and I can't find any reference to it in the GCC or GNU ld manuals.  Are you using some different linker?  Maybe if you add a `-v` to your link line and look at the actual linker invocation it will be helpful?

Comment: If you run `file <path-to>/libnetpbm.a` what is the output?  Is this really a static library (archive)?  Or is it a shared library, but with an extremely misleading name?  On POSIX systems names are not definitive.  The type of the file is determined by its contents, not its name.  Maybe when you built or installed `libnetpbm.a` you did something unexpected.

Comment: @MadScientist for build the library, I have this makefile: https://pastebin.com/xxAG46WS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in fact in the way I was building the library. I change the Makefile from this:

```
libnetpbm: ${obj_dir}/netpbm.o ${obj_dir}/bitmap.o ${obj_dir}/graymap.o ${obj_dir}/pixmap.o
    g++ -g -shared -o ${release_dir}/libnetpbm.so ${obj_dir}/netpbm.o ${obj_dir}/bitmap.o ${obj_dir}/graymap.o ${obj_dir}/pixmap.o -Wl,--out-implib,${release_dir}/libnetpbm.a
```

to that:

```
libnetpbm: ${obj_dir}/netpbm.o ${obj_dir}/bitmap.o ${obj_dir}/graymap.o ${obj_dir}/pixmap.o
    ar rcs ${release_dir}/libnetpbm.a ${obj_dir}/netpbm.o ${obj_dir}/bitmap.o ${obj_dir}/graymap.o ${obj_dir}/pixmap.o
    g++ -g -shared -o ${release_dir}/libnetpbm.so ${obj_dir}/netpbm.o ${obj_dir}/bitmap.o ${obj_dir}/graymap.o ${obj_dir}/pixmap.o
```